# Libvirt Libvirtd virtualbox remote virsh list --all empty

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, apparmor

Good afternoon,

first of all excuse my english i'am a foreigner, and it's my first post...

I got some trouble using virtualbox and libvirt on a LTS 14.04.

I try to do a home sandbox with cuckoo (wich use libvirt).

Server details:
Ubuntu 14.04 - Libvirt 1.2.2 - virtualbox 4.3.34
using virsh (*virsh -c vbox:///session
list --all*) I get this

```
 ID    Nom                            État
----------------------------------------------------
 1     Cuckoo                         en cours d'exécution
 -     Win_10_64b                     fermé
 -     Win_7_32b                      fermé
 -     Win_7_64b                      fermé
 -     Win_8.1_64b                    fermé
 -     Win_8_64b                      fermé
```

My client
Ubuntu 14.04 - Libvirt 1.2.2
When I connect to my client (cuckoo)
using virsh (*sudo virsh -c vbox+tcp://xxxxxxxx@192.168.56.1/system list --all
*) I get this

```
 ID    Nom                            État
----------------------------------------------------
```

Virsh # version
On server

```
Compiled against library: libvirt 1.2.2
Using library: libvirt 1.2.2
Utilisation de l'API : VBOX 1.2.2
Exécution de l'hyperviseur : VBOX 4.3.34
```

On client

```
Compiled against library: libvirt 1.2.2
Using library: libvirt 1.2.2
Utilisation de l'API : VBOX 1.2.2
Exécution de l'hyperviseur : VBOX 4.3.34
```

On server 
/etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf

```
listen_tls = 0
#tls_port = "16514"
listen_tcp = 1
tcp_port = "16509"
listen_addr = "192.168.56.1"
mdns_name = "Virtualization Host SOC Demo"
unix_sock_group = "libvirtd"
#unix_sock_ro_perms = "0777"
unix_sock_rw_perms = "0770"
auth_unix_ro = "none"
auth_unix_rw = "none"
auth_tcp = "none"
log_level = 2
log_outputs="2:file:/var/log/libvirt/deamon.log"
```

/etc/default/libvirt-bin

```
start_libvirtd="yes"
libvirtd_opts="-d -l"
```

Other infos (it may help someone one day...):
I order to get libvirt support vbox, I had to recompile it(on both server and client)  using

```
sudo apt-get update
apt-get source -d libvirt
sudo apt-get build-dep libvirt
dpkg-source -x libvirt*dsc
cd libvirt-1.2.2
sudo ./configure --with-vbox
sudo make distclean
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -b -rfakeroot
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i libvirt-bin_xxxx.deb libvirt0_xxxx.deb
```

After that, I could not connect to my "libvirt server' I found via *dmesg | grep libvirtd* tha apparmor was not configured properly to allow libvirtd

I add in */etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.libvirtd* these lines

```
/usr/{lib,lib64}/virtualbox/VBoxXPCOMIPCD Ux,  
/usr/{lib,lib64}/virtualbox/VBoxSVC Ux,   
dbus bus=system,
signal,  
ptrace,
```

And I finaly succeded to connect via *sudo virsh -c vbox+tcp://xxxxxxxx@192.168.56.1/system* but I don't see my VMs :(

I wich someone get (and solved) the same issue...

Best regards,
Physaphaé

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found  a solution

this is a right problem. Virtualbox must be run as root (`sudo virtualbox &`) >> **Success**
Even if you specified user with `user@IP` it does not care...

By the way, I tried:

- Create a user account (same name, same password), on both machine >> **Failed**
- Setting up a sasl authentication >> **Failed**